# Fractional Linear Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, mobius-transformation

> Suppose that $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ad-bc=1$. Let $T$ be the fractional linear transformation $$z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
>   Show that if $a=i, b=-i, c=1, d=i$, then the corresponding fraction linear transformation maps the upper half plane onto the unit disc.

I tried to find the image of $$w=\frac{iz-i}{z+i}$$
From here, $$z=\frac{-i-wi}{w-i}$$
Hence \begin{align}
x+iy&=z \\
&= \frac{-i-wi}{w-i} \\
&=\frac{-i-i(u+iv)}{u+i(v-1)} \\
&=\frac{(-i-iu+v)(u-iv+i)}{u^2+(v-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{1-v+u}{u^2+(v-1)^2}+i\frac{-u-u^2-v^2+v}{u^2+(v-1)^2} \\
\end{align}
Thus we want the image of $y>0$, so $$\frac{-u-u^2-v^2+v}{u^2+(v-1)^2}>0$$
But this does not yield the unit circle. Where have I gone wrong in my method?

Comment: Are you familiar with properties of Mobius transformations?

Comment: It is a new concept, so not entirely. I am comfortable with special cases of Mobius transformations, such as inverse maps.

Comment: Note that $ad-bc=i^2+i\ne1$ which does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $a=1$? Because your transformation maps 1 to 0. It means it doesn't map the boundary of the upper half plane to the boundary of the unit disk. (and hence can't map the upper half plane to the unit disk)

Comment: Just double checked, $a=i$. Do you think the question is incorrect?

Comment: I guess so. Because Mobius transformation must map boundaries to boundaries. The boundary of the upper half plane is the real axis and your transformation maps 1 to 0 while 0 is not a point on the boundary of the unit disk.

Comment: Agreed. I will raise this with the lecturer and update the question (if necessary) after consultation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you have to prove two things

First:  if $\Im(z)>0$ then $|w|\leq 1$

*(and if you try $z=-2+i$ you will see this is not true, so your problem is incorrect).*

Second: if $|w|\leq 1$ then $\Im(z)>0$

Comment: Was my method correct though? Or was it completely invalid haha

Comment: Second part it is, but you didn't take into a count that $|w|\leq 1$, that is $u^2+v^2\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

If you change to  $a=1, b=-i, c=1, d=i$, then the image of $z\in \mathbb R$ is $\{w\  | \ |w|=1\}$, since $z+i$ is the conjugate of $z-i$. But $i$ goes to $0$, and infinity goes to 1, so by continuity the upper half plane goes to the interior of the circle, and the lower half plane to the exterior. Since the function is a bijection of $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ to itself, you get the result.